# Stop selenium test execution from eclipse

Tags: eclipse, selenium

My scenarios starts to fail, and I have so many scenarios. I need to terminate test execution (I dont want to wait). How I can do that from ECLIPSE?

I am avare of the fact that there is a some button to stop test execution from eclipse. But i do not know how to add it, is it default or I can get it as extension from eclipse market place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be the same as stopping any app in Eclipse. The stop button can be found above the console to the right (Picture below).

However keep in mind that this will then not close the browser driver and you will need to do that manually. Easiest way for me was using the command "taskkill -IM chromedriver.exe -f", chromedriver can only be killed when the force (-f) flag is used. Alternatively you could add some more functionallity to your app to allow you to break within the app that will stop the execution and close the driver.

[Stop button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pt4ti.png)